# Qt Androidd Extras: Why is there an error in "import androidx.XXX" (java files)?

Tags: android, qt

I am trying to use Qt AndroidExtras. I found an Android example of the functionality need for me (on java) and want to transfer it to Qt.
I get error on lines (other imports compile successfully):

```
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManagerCompat;
```

> ```
> error: package androidx.core.app does not exist import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
> error: package androidx.core.hardware.fingerprint does not exist import androidx.core.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManagerCompat;
> ```

This code in AndroidStudio builds without errors and works.
Tried to set properties:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

but it doesn't work

Why is this error occurring and how can I fix it?

Here is my build.gradle file that Qt created:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2'

    }
 }

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'])
 }
android {
    /*******************************************************
     * The following variables:
     * - androidBuildToolsVersion,
     * - androidCompileSdkVersion
     * - qt5AndroidDir - holds the path to qt android files
     *                   needed to build any Qt application
     *                   on Android.
     *
     * are defined in gradle.properties file. This file is
     * updated by QtCreator and androiddeployqt tools.
     * Changing them manually might break the compilation!
     *******************************************************/
    compileSdkVersion androidCompileSdkVersion.toInteger()

    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = [qt5AndroidDir + '/src', 'src', 'java']
            aidl.srcDirs = [qt5AndroidDir + '/src', 'src', 'aidl']
            res.srcDirs = [qt5AndroidDir + '/res', 'res']
            resources.srcDirs = ['resources']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
       }
    }

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.incremental = true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    // Do not compress Qt binary resources file
    aaptOptions {
        noCompress 'rcc'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        resConfig "en"
        minSdkVersion = qtMinSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion = qtTargetSdkVersion
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems you need to adjust your build.gradle file.

Comment: I added my build.gradle file to this topic. Tell me please what I can try to improve there?

Comment: You need to adjust `dependencies` section. I'm not a very experienced Android developer so can't give you an exact example. Please use Google. :)